# C++: "спрятать" классы и структуры

Tags: c++, xlib

Здравствуйте! У меня имеется класс **MyWindow** (написан с использованием XLib). Поскольку в XLib есть структура с названием **Window**, я не могу создать объект с именем **Window**. А если другой девелопер попробует создать таковой, компилятор вывалит три короба ошибок. Как спрятать структуру **Window**? Или лучше вообще всю библиотеку?

Comment: Использовать namespace.

Comment: ```namespace hidden{ #include <X11/X.h> }; ... class MyWindow{ ... private: hidden::Window *window; };``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [идиому **pimpl**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111602/) для скрытия реализации.

```
// --- MyWindow.h ---
class MyWindow
{
public:
    MyWindow();
    ~MyWindow();

    // ... публичные методы ...
    void show();

private:
    class Private;
    Private *d; // или std::unique_ptr<Private> для C++11
};

// -- MyWindow.cpp --
#include "MyWindow.h"
#include <X11/X.h> 

class MyWindow::Private
{
public:
    // ... приватные данные и методы ...
    void show() {
        // показать окно
    }
    Window *window; 
};

MyWindow::MyWindow() : d(new Private) {
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow()
{
    delete d;
}

void MyWindow::show() {
    d->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто положить свой класс в своё пространство имён.